# AFNetworking 2 migration for a newbie

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I´m just trying my first steps with version 2 of AFNetworking.

Because of the new version the existing online tutorials like
the afnetworking-crash-course by Ray Wenderlich
doesn´t work anymore.

From the AFNetworking 2 migration guide I´ve got the following code:

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetwor…Migration-Guide

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/foo.json"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
} failure:nil];
[operation start];
```

At this time I´ve already added
the import

```
#import "AFNetworking.h"
```

to the .pch-file.

The problem:
I always get the error message, AFJSONSerializer is undeclared.

What step did I forget?

Best regards

Frank

Comment: Please mark the answer correct if it is. And welcome to Stack Overflow :D

Answer (score 5):

That should be `AFJSONResponseSerializer`, not `AFJSONSerializer`.